# How to re-enter a stopped docker container, which originally is not run with interactive TTY?

Tags: docker

The command

`docker run ubuntu:15.10 /bin/mkdir /root/test`

1. creates and run a new container on image ubuntu:15.10
2. makes a new directory `/root/test` in the container
3. stops the container

Now, how can I re-enter this container and check if the directory `/root/test` is really create.

I think `docker start <container_id>` cannot achieve my goal.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/

Comment: So I have to commit this container to a new image, and then run another container on this new image.

Comment: yes, changes are not saved unless you explicitly save them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. But you can do

`docker run ubuntu:15.10 bash`

then as you have a prompt

`/bin/mkdir /root/test`

and in another terminal you can

`docker commit -t mymkdir container_id`

Then, if you exit from your started container, you will be able to

`docker run -it mymkdir bash`

and you will find your previously created directory